# Error loading type library DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A(Type_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))

Tags: c#, exception, dll, desktop

I'm developing a c# desktop app on a customer's dev machine. Part of the app involves using a third party dll to communicate with another application installed on the box.

My app builds fine and even executes to a certain degree but whilst debugging I noticed I was getting the error

```
"Error loading type library DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A(Type_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY))"
```

when I was instantiating the third party object and I think it may be setting up errors further down the line.

I looked into the exception Source and `'mscorlib'` is referenced - not sure what relevance that would have?

Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: try unrigister, then register the COM dll

Comment: Thanks Matt - is that the mscorlib dll?

Comment: No, the COM component.  Contact the vendor or author if you need help, some COM components don't support calling them from the wrong thread or the MTA at all.